# Finding the conditions of a system of equations for a type of solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Consider the system of equations $x$,$y$, and $z$,
>
> $$2x+3y-z=p$$
> $$x-2z=-5$$
> $$qx+9y+5z=8$$
>
> where $p$ and $q$ are real.
>
> Find the values of $p$ and $q$ for which this system has:
>
> **(i)** a unique solution
>
> **(ii)** an infinite number of solutions
>
> **(iii)** no solutions

---

I understand part **(i)** Here is how I did it:

The system of equations has a unique solution when the determinant is not equal to zero.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & -2 \\ q & 9 & 5 \end{bmatrix} \neq 0$$

$$2(18)-3(5+2q)-1(9) \neq 0 \implies q \neq 2$$

I believe $p$ can be any value.

So the answer is : $q\neq 2$

---

I know that when $q = 2$. Then the system of equations don't  have a unique solution or no solution.

I don't know the **condition** that separate the part (ii) and (iii) and

Hence, I don't know how to  find the values of q. Please help me.

Comment: I suppose also a typo in the first equation (last $x$ should be $z$, I suppose).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici fixed the typo

Comment: @Amzoti yes it is an $z$ . Ummmm you mean reduced row echleon form? If so yes.

Comment: @Amzoti Oh yes I tried :/ but no it didn't. Gimme a second Il add it to the question

Comment: @Amzoti UMMM can you tell me how do I put echleon form using latex? Like it should be (x x x | x) << I don't know how to get that | part

Comment: @Amzoti I understood :D thank you

Answer (score 0):

if $q=2$ and $p=-4$ we have $y=\frac{1}{2}(-1-x),z=\frac{5+x}{2}$
if $q\ne 2$ we get $x=-\frac{3(4+p)}{q-2},y=\frac{1}{6}{(5+2p-3x)} ,z=\frac{5+x}{2}$

Comment: Don't get this :/

Comment: you have to distinguish to cases $q=2$ and $p=-4$

Comment: and $q\ne 2$ can you calculate this?

Comment: Understood my question :)